# 555 timer circuitry

Tags: control, 555

I have a 555 pulse generator controlling a relay going a little faster than 1hz. It  is hooked up to start up when it receives positive voltage from the switched accessory circuit of a vehicle. That much works fine, but I would like to limit the number of pulses it puts out to around 15 or so, and then stop until the next time the vehicle is switched back on. Using *another* 555 chip, I thought about making a "one-shot" pulse generator to control the first one, but it seems that this circuit requires a negative pulse to initiate it. That doesn't quite work for the automated status that I require. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can convert a positive pulse to a negative one with a single transistor and a resistor.

Comment: True, but it's not a positive pulse, per se. The car is started, so the positive remains positive until the car is turned off again, but the negative must be a short pulse to trigger the 555.

Comment: I thought of a rather inelegant way to do it using two additional relays and a 1000uf capacitor, but I was really hoping to do it in a more streamlined fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to add a counter (there are still available 4-bit counters that can count 16 pulses). Simply have the counter clock off the existing 555 timer pulses. An R/C time circuit can provide a simple reset to assure that the counter resets to 0 each time the power first comes on. When the counter reaches full count use the output to reset the 555 chip so it does not produce any more pulses until the power cycle reset.

Comment: I considered a decade counter, but I had just hoped there'd be an obvious way to do it with (2)555 chips. The necessity of the negative pulse to trigger the single-event timer which controls how long the pulse generator runs, has proven something of a quandary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample circuit how you can generate your pulse train with two 555 timers. The first 555 triggers just after the power comes on. When it triggers it takes the second 555 out of reset and allows it to generate the desired 15 or so pulses at about a 1 second rate.

Note that the diode D1 is used to give better control over selecting the on and off duty cycle of the repeating pulses rather than the normally seen configuration for an astable 555 circuit.

[image]

Comment: Michael Karas - thanks for the schematic. Using a resistor and capacitor on the trigger was just the tip I needed. I actually POWER the second chip with the output of the first one, so I just have a jumper from pin 3 of 555(1) to pin 8 of 555(2) and it works like a charm.

Comment: In fact, here it is:    https://youtu.be/GddvjG5WyT8

Comment: vote it up if you like it,

Comment: This is my first time here. How do I do that?

Comment: Look at the arrow buttons near the upper left of the answer. A more comprehensive site usage can be read in the help section.

Comment: So, my frustration is through the roof. I had it working, and now not. I fully reconstructed it. The self-trigger on powering up works sometimes, and sometimes not. I don't get it. I used a different (much smaller) capacitor value than your 1uf, simply because it was all I had on hand, as well as something lower than 100K. I think I used a 28K. How crucial are the values? Can you explain what the "mechanism" is with regard to the resistor/capacitor combination on pin 2 that causes it to self-trigger on powering up? In my 555 literature (a SAMS book and Forest Mims notebook) no mention is made

Comment: on self-triggering a single-event timer on powering up. They ALL talk about a ground pulse trigger which must be manually created with a momentary switch. Why am I getting sporadic success?

Comment: @ViiiCards - The idea of the resistor/capacitor on the TRIG pin of the U1 555 is to hold the TRIG pin low long enough so that the power comes up and the TRIG comparator inside the part can set the internal 555 flip-flop. You will probably need a bigger capacitor and a bigger resistor. With too small of values the TRIG pin will almost just track the +12V coming up and and look "high" all the time. Also if you tried to just tie TRIG to GND it forces the internal FF to stay set all the time and fails to let the THRS pin clear the FF to end the output pulse. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) The additional beauty of the R/C on the TRIG pin is that it eventually allows the TRIG signal to go high so that later the THRS pin can do its deed. So I suspect if you found a 1uF or even a 4.7uF capacitor and tried to do the larger resistor much closer to the 100K that you would find improvement in behavior. It is possible that with your 28K resistor and a 4.7uF cap it may work. 28K is about 1/4 of the original 100K and 4.7uF is almost 5x the original 1uF and this would produce an R/C delay not so far off the designed value. If you have a really (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) slow rise time on the +12V then it may very well require a larger resistor value and a larger capacitor value. On the circuit simulation that I did I set the rise time of the +12V to 50msec.

Comment: Thanks once again. I saw another thread on a different site in which the guy used a 1M resistor and a .1uf capacitor, so it would seem the "magic" number for reliable self-triggering is 100K, multiplying the resistor value and capacitor value. I changed my values, and am VERY pleased with the result.

Comment: One last question. Although I am quite satisfied with the performance of timer one's output actually powering timer 2, I am curious about your schematic. The blue line comes from pin 3 a tad, and stops. Which pin does it go to? Is it linked to its own pin 6 AND pin 2 of timer 2?

Comment: The U1 pin 3 is no connect.